# What are the units used in the "last seen" message in Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

In Google Hangouts I sometimes see messages like this:

> last seen 1mo ago

Does `mo` represent `month` here? And are there other "strange" units abbreviations used in Hangouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"mo" is a standard 2-character abbreviation for "month".

It doesn't seem strange to me. You also don't list what other "strange" abbreviations you're seeing, but here's some you might see:

```
yr  year
dy  day
wk  week
hr  hour
mi  minute
```